# Oracle square brackets are not escapable

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have oracle behaviour not matching the documentation.

This is a sql sample I have to describe my issue:

```
with t as (
select 'name' as s from dual
union all
select 'name[' as s from dual
union all
select 'na[me' as s from dual
union all
select '[name' as s from dual
union all
select 'name]' as s from dual
union all
select 'na]me' as s from dual
union all
select ']name' as s from dual
union all
select 'name[]' as s from dual
union all
select 'na[]me' as s from dual
union all
select '[]name' as s from dual
union all
select '[name]' as s from dual
union all
select 'na[me]' as s from dual
union all
select '[na]me' as s from dual
)
select s from t where t.s like '%]%' escape '\'
```

Every piece of documentation I could find says exactly the same: You should escape square brackets ([]) in your like queries.

But for some reason, this is what I have:

sql:

`select s from t where t.s like '%]%' escape '\'`

output:

```
name]
na]me
]name
name[]
na[]me
[]name
[name]
na[me]
[na]me
```

sql:

`select s from t where t.s like '%\]%' escape '\'`

output:

```
ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character
01424. 00000 -  "missing or illegal character following the escape character"
*Cause:    The character following the escape character in LIKE pattern is
           missing or not one of the escape character, '%', or '_'.
*Action:   Remove the escape character or specify the missing character.
Error at Line: 28 Column: 32
```

At both cases "with" stays the same, I just add\remove escape character from my "like".

I'm a little bit confused, this is not something I could expect, according to documentaion.

I'm not an oracle expert, so I suppose I'm missing something here.

My versions are:

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;

Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: "Every piece of documentation I could find says exactly the same" - can you point us to *Oracle* documentation that says that? Rather than, say SQL Server documentation? (Or were you perhaps looking at regular expressions?)

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes, you're right, I've messed up, mentions of this needed to be escaped I've found in SQL server documentation and oracle "CONTAINS" reference. Problem solved as it never existed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only characters that can be escaped are the ones that have special meaning: `_` and `%` and the escape character itself. Nothing else needs to be escaped. `[` and `]` are not special, not for normal `LIKE`. Just omit your escape clause altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, it was simply wrong reference I was looking at.